# How do I start with Watson Data Analytics for iOS App?

Tags: ios, analytics, ibm-watson

Watson analytics : https://www.ibm.com/analytics/watson-analytics/us-en/
is having a lot information but not the one that I need. 
I want to know if I can make it with iOS App. The other services like text-to-speech, translation, news, speech-to-text , etc I have tried. They all come with Watson iOS SDK. but analytics is something different and not in SDK. Not getting where do I start from.

Comment: Are you talking about [IBM Digital Analytics](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPG9M/Analytics/sdk_container.html) or does it simply have to be Watson?

Comment: Analytics provided by Watson APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watson Analytics is not part of the Watson iOS SDK.  There is a REST API you can use if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the REST API as suggested above, and use the developer center for Watson analytics to use API available here - https://developer.ibm.com/watson-analytics/

The complete information about importing the data and using API explorer is covered in the [Getting started guide here](https://developer.ibm.com/watson-analytics/#getstarted).